# Using Apex Core Functionality in Custom App

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I would like to use the Oracle Apex 5.1 IDE Query Builder in a custom application.  When tracing the URL calls, it looks like the following objects are called below.  Does anyone know whether there is a Query Builder component that can be exported from the Apex IDE and imported into a custom app, or if there is a way to replicate the functionality based on the urls below?  Appreciate any thoughts/help - thanks!

Application:  4500
Page:  1002

```
.0.0.1:8080/apex/f?p=4500:1002:2195359818348::NO::: 
.0.0.1:8080/i/app_ui/css/Core.min.css?v=5.1.3.00.05
.0.0.1:8080/i/app_ui/css/Theme-Standard.min.css?v=5.1.3.00.05 
.0.0.1:8080/i/css/apex_builder.min.css?v=5.1.3.00.05
.0.0.1:8080/i/css/apex_ui.min.css?v=5.1.3.00.05"
.0.0.1:8080/i/apex_ui/css/Core.min.css?v=5.1.3.00.05
.0.0.1:8080/i/apex_ui/css/Theme-Standard.min.css?v=5.1.3.00.05
.0.0.1:8080/i/libraries/jquery/2.2.3/jquery-2.2.3.min.js?v=5.1.3.00.05
.0.0.1:8080/i/libraries/apex/minified/desktop.min.js?v=5.1.3.00.05
.0.0.1:8080/apex/wwv_flow.js_messages?p_app_id=4500^&p_lang=en^&p_version=5.1.3.00.05-474390
.0.0.1:8080/i/libraries/apex/minified/legacy.min.js?v=5.1.3.00.05
.0.0.1:8080/i/apex_ui/js/minified/builder_all.min.js?v=5.1.3.00.05
.0.0.1:8080/i/qb/drag.png
.0.0.1:8080/i/green_arrow_up.gif
.0.0.1:8080/i/green_arrow_down.gif" 
.0.0.1:8080/i/delete.gif
.0.0.1:8080/i/qb/qb_core.js?v=5.1.3.00.05
.0.0.1:8080/apex/f?p=4500:0:2195359818348:APPLICATION_PROCESS=qb_get_saved_query" 
.0.0.1:8080/apex/f?p=4500:1002:2195359818348::NO:::
.0.0.1:8080/i/libraries/apex/minified/interactiveGrid.min.js?v=5.1.3.00.05" -H "Referer: .0.0.1:8080/apex/f?p=4500:1002:2195359818348::NO:::"
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.  Long answer:  The URLs that have a `/apex/f?p=4500` format are calls to a PL/SQL procedure named `P` which is proprietary Oracle code.

```
SQL> describe apex_050100.p
PROCEDURE apex_050100.p
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out Default?
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------ --------
 N                              VARCHAR2                IN     DEFAULT
 P_MIME_TYPE                    VARCHAR2                IN     DEFAULT
 P_INLINE                       VARCHAR2                IN     DEFAULT
```

So the URL in your example

```
 .0.0.1:8080/apex/f?p=4500:0:2195359818348:APPLICATION_PROCESS=qb_get_saved_query"
```

Calls the procedure

```
apex_050100.p('4500:0:2195359818348:APPLICATION_PROCESS=qb_get_saved_query"'
```

And if you try to get the definition of the procedure, you will see it is wrapped (encrypted):

```
SQL> select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('PROCEDURE', 'P', 'APEX_050100') from dual;


DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('PROCEDURE','P','APEX_050100')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE OR REPLACE NONEDITIONABLE PROCEDURE "APEX_050100"."P" wrapped
a000000
1
abcd
....
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
7
1df 148
PySktRSwPuir/a3q2cinKtaJ5KMwg2Npr+UVfC/PwT+VGYOsXY9cjpuK37IUBcgap0GspV2o
MBYc5D8Lun4oGFvBS5Hf2UeKq7q7LRFW5iiIL0fINltI/pTE9hZLXfCbZ/AJCjYi3TZiKjma
iOTy6fHxRrvCGsOwyB2/+gzkUcgh7IVl0RtVj5m85uztTMFUQ7KCkwUc5ib83xbcrJW8gKQh
e8ZEyd5ySMbZOpbSxrVeV0xk3kEgyZRtvC0hKsgYfVf3LSINDCZ8EThYZyQvhfGVvER+v2cK
XT2ohnKs0RfogrIdhtrJEhp8E0/aB2wX1g== 
....
```

Comment: Mark,  Thanks for taking time to answer and explain!  Too bad it can't be used, but it was worth a try!

Comment: Sure; feel free to mark this answer as correct /accepted to make it easier for  others to find, and to help those looking for questions to answer to know this was answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can import application from APEX_INSTALLATION_ARCHIVE\apex\builder\f4500.sql into your own workspace and then check page 1002.